# Meaning of "has my best wishes"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

What does "has my best wishes" mean here?

> he told his long-suffering publisher John Murray that Napoleon 'has my
>   best wishes to manure the fields of France with an invading army'
>
> [Source](http://www.delanceyplace.com/view_archives.php?1806)

Isn't this supposed to be "my best wished for him to manure...?" because it means
"I wish that Napoleon will manure the fields of France with an invading army"?

Answer (score 1):

**best wishes** is an idiomatic expression meaning that the person whose wishes they are desires a particular (positive) outcome for someone else; it is often used toward people who are ill (*best wishes for a speedy recovery*), but in this case it is used toward Napoleon (Murray wants him to win the war).

The suggested **has my best wished** is incorrect in both usage and grammar; **has** is the simple present indicative of **have**, indicating possession (Napoleon has something), and **my best wishes** (for victory) is what he has.

Comment: Here's a typo in your answer : The suggested" has my best wished". It's not wished, it's " has my best wishes".

Comment: @Sweet72 Read the question. The OP was specifically asking about the phrase **my best wished**.